# Sending values of Dropdown list and list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, relationship

I have three models:

```
public class Student {
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Father { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Gender { get; set; }
    public int EmployID { get; set; }
    public int RankID  { get; set; }
    public int CollegeID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> OstadCourses2 { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {

    }

}

public class Course
{

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> OstadCourses1 { get; set; }

    public Course()
    {

    }

}

public class StudentCourse
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentCourseId { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Ostad Ostad14 { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course14 { get; set; }

    public OstadCourse()
    {
    }

    public OstadCourse(int ostadId, int courseId)
    {
        OstadId = ostadId;
        CourseId = courseId;
    }
}
```

I have created a list of students. I want to create a view that there is a dropdown for the courses and a list of students with their properties. Then we click on a button, bind Courseid and Student Id in database and a list of student and courses was shown.

I have tried. But without any success. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your subsequent description,

> I want to create a view that there is a dropdown for the courses and a list of students with their properties. Then we click on a button, bind Courseid and Student Id in database and a list of student and courses was shown

Here is part of the implementation code that I provide for you, which you can use as a reference.

My controller:

```
public class StudentCourse : Controller
{
     private readonly SchoolDbcontext _context;

     public StudentCourse(SchoolDbcontext context)
     {
         _context = context;
     }
     public ActionResult StudentList()
   {
       // Retrieve a list of students and courses from your database
       var students = _context.Students.Include(s => s.CourseStudents).ThenInclude(cs => cs.Course).ToList();
       var courses = _context.Courses.ToList();
       var viewModel = new StudentCourseViewModel
       {
           Students = students,
                 
           Courses = new SelectList(courses, "CourseId", "Subject").ToList()
       };
            

       return View(viewModel);
   }


     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult BindStudentToCourse(int SelectedCourseId, int[] SelectedStudents) //
     {
         if (SelectedCourseId != 0 && SelectedStudents != null)
         {
             foreach (int studentId in SelectedStudents)
             {
                 var existingRecord = _context.CourseStudents.FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.CourseId == SelectedCourseId && cs.StudentId == studentId);
                 if (existingRecord == null)
                 {
                     var courseStudent = new CourseStudent
                     {
                         StudentId = studentId,
                         CourseId = SelectedCourseId
                     };

                     _context.CourseStudents.Add(courseStudent);
                 }

                 _context.SaveChanges();
             }

         }

             return RedirectToAction("StudentList");
         }
     }
}
```

My pages:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BindStudentToCourse", "StudentCourse", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedCourseId, "Select a Course:")
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCourseId, Model.Courses, "Select a Course", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th> Studentname</th>
            <th> Course</th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Students.Count; i++)
        {
         
            <tr>
                <td>@Model.Students[i].StudentName</td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var course in Model.Students[i].CourseStudents)
                        {
                            <li>@course.Course.Subject</li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </td>
                
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBox("SelectedStudents", new { value = Model.Students[i].StudentId })
                    @Html.Hidden("Students[" + i + "].StudentId", Model.Students[i].StudentId)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Bind Students to Course</button>
```

When I choose three students bind to a Course:
[image]

When I click button :
[image]
I could get CourseID and student who selected by me.

In the end, the student and the course were successfully connected:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your problem description I understand that there are two situations you may face.

In the first scenario, you need two dropdown lists, one for students and another for courses. After clicking, you want to bind students to specific courses and get the corresponding updated list.

In the second scenario, you want to associate each student with their respective course by selecting from a dropdown in the course column within a student list.

Answer (score 0):

I created the following view to answer my question:

```
 @model DataLayer.OstadCourse

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>OstadCourse</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CourseId, "CourseId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CourseId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OstadId, "OstadId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("OstadId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OstadId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>*@

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OstadName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OstadName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OstadName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OstadFamily, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OstadFamily, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OstadFamily, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Father, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Father, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Father, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhonNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhonNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhonNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kodmelli, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Kodmelli, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Kodmelli, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AcademicRank, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AcademicRank, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AcademicRank, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CollegeName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CollegeName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CollegeName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35207871)

Comment: @JeremyCaney are you sure? the question asks for a view...

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine are you sure? the question asks for a view...

Comment: @starball: Thank you for bringing that up. You’re right. I’m not entirely sure what this is—but I’m also not certain it’s _NAA_. I’ve retracted my original flag.